# PHP: connecting to db on host IP vs using 127.0.0.1

Tags: php, database, hosting, localhost

When I connect to a mysql database in PHP, and the db is hosted on the same machine as the site itself, I can either use the machine's IP, or 127.0.0.1

Is there a difference in performance between the two? Is there a guideline for when I should use 127.0.0.1?

Comment: No there is not, You could also use `localhost`

Comment: Use `tracert` (or `traceroute`) to see.  The machine should be smart enough to realize its own address, and use a loopback.

Comment: If this is for mysql, connecting using 'localhost' will try to use a unixdomain socket rather than tcp, which is somewhat more efficient. But as far as the client app is concerned, there's no operational difference.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/422376/localhost-vs-127-0-0-1-vs-computer-name-vs-ip-in-url

Comment: @MarcB There's an interesting little titbit I've never heard/come across before, do you have a reference for that?

Comment: @dave: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=31577

Comment: If you are connecting to something on your local machine, *always* use `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` over an IP address associated with a NIC on the machine. If you use an actual IP address and you change that IP address somewhere down the line, you will break your application. Efficiency-wise there's unlikely to be a large enough difference to be meaningful if there is one at all, because a local address is a local address and it will never be sent out to the network unless you adjust the routing table to force it to, but in terms of *maintainability*, using the loopback is definitely best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is probably an incredibly small (unnoticeable) performance benefit to connecting via 127.0.0.1, since it will not require as many firewall/routing rules to be checked when you connect.

If you have the option, connect via the unix domain socket (usually something like `/tmp/mysql.sock`). There is a definite performance increase to connecting via this method, as well as improved security.

**Edit**

According to the comment by MarcB apparently connecting via `localhost` will automatically attempt to connect via the domain socket. As stated this is the preferred and most performant method,

Answer (score 3):

When you want to connect to the local machine, you should always use `localhost`, or `127.0.0.1`, because the server may deny access to any other interface. Additional when the IP changes you have a huge amount of work to do to change every occurence of the IP you placed somewhere.

However, the loopback address should be slightly faster, but I guess no one can measure it in a reliable way, thus: You shouldn't care. And when you are using loopback anyway (as suggested above), then you are on the safe side.

Answer (score 2):

Both requests ends up hitting the kernel routing table before going out to an interface. There shouldn't be any impact unless the loopback address has in-kernel optimizations.

Comment: As far as I know the loopback _has_ optimizations. No evidence, just heard somewhere some day.

Comment: It would make sense kernel developers would optimize the loopback interface.

Answer (score 0):

The performance should be the same unless there are some extremely weird network configuration on the server.

As for guidelines, well, that depends, if your db server is likely to change in the future maybe you should store that url in some xml file or any file so the application can read that configuration later. By doing that you don't have to worry for using any ip or even the hostname or localhost. you may even try to look into DynamicDns for this.

If the server is unlikely to change then don't worry too much. Use 'localhost' instead of any ip just in case the server ip changes. The file option is still a good practice but it won't hurt you too much if you don't use it.